# Check if array does NOT contain a certain value

Tags: java

I know that if I want to check if an array does contain a certain value I should use `Arrays.asList(arrayName).contains(valueName)`.
But how do I check if that value is not present? At first I just thought of putting ! in front like:

```
!Arrays.asList(arrayName).contains(valueName)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

I even tried writing the if statement like this:

```
if (Arrays.asList(arrayName).contains(valueName)==false)
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the code:

```
public int[] duplikati(int[] tabela){
    int len = tabela.length;
    int c = 0;
    int[] count = new int[len];
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if (Arrays.asList(count).contains(tabela[i])==false){
            c++;
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[c];
    int d = 0;
    for (int j=0;j<len;j++){
        if (Arrays.asList(result).contains(tabela[j])==false){
            System.out.print(tabela[j]+" ");
            result[d] = tabela[j];
            d++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: that should work just fine. Have you debugged your code, to see if the value is indeed there? does your class overwrite the equals method, or does it use the referential comparison from Object?

Comment: Posting a code snippet to explain your problem would be a first right step.

Comment: What are these variables `count` and `tabela`?

Comment: I posted the code. Count represents the name of the array and tabela[i] represents the value from another array.

Comment: Just as a note, `contains` in arrays and `ArrayList` is a slow operation (`O(n)`). It needs to search through the whole collection. Data-structures like `HashSet` where made to answer a `contains` query in super fast time (`O(1)`).

Answer (score 1):

In, this specific case when you pass an array of primitive types into `Arrays.asList` you'll get back a List with a *single* element which is the provided array.

So, when you do:

```
Arrays.asList(arrayName).contains(valueName)
```

The call `Arrays.asList(arrayName)` will return a `List<int[]>` and then when you call `contains` the `valueName` will get boxed to an `Integer` and then get's compared with the element(s) in the list. because an `int[]` is never equal to an integer value, the `contains` call will always return `false`.

Solution 1 - change the type of your arrays from `int[]` to `Integer[]`, then everything should work as you expect.

Solution 2 - Assuming you do not want to change the type of the arrays for some reason, then you can do:

```
final int index = i;
if(Arrays.stream(count).noneMatch(e -> e == tabela[index])){...}
```

inside the for loops.

You can think of the `noneMatch` method as `!Arrays.asList(someArray).contains(someValue)` if it helps.

Similarly, you can check if the array contains an element with:

```
final int index = i;
if(Arrays.stream(count).anyMatch(e -> e == tabela[index])){...}
```

You can think of the `anyMatch` method as `Arrays.asList(someArray).contains(someValue)` if it helps.

Comment: What am I supposed to put in instead of e -> e?It says cannot find symbol.

Comment: @Sebastjan what version of java are you using? the lambda token (`->`) is only valid from Java-8 and above. since that doesn't work for you then you can go with the first solution I have suggested. alternatively, if you still want to work with an array of primitives then you can create your own contains method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 stream api as follows

```
Integer arr[]=new Integer[]{1,2,30,61};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).stream().noneMatch(element>element==10));
```

You can go through the below link for explaination of
[noneMatch()](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/11/java-8-stream-nonematch-example/)

Comment: you can do it better with `int arr[]=new int[]{1,2,30,61};
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).noneMatch(element -> element == 10));`